# how to v-for drive canvas tag and save things in the canvas

Tags: canvas, vue.js, v-for

there is source code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/9lqnroooxr

How to v-for drive accurately canvas tag?

Is there such a class or a directive?

Comment: What you want to achieve and what you are getting ? also share any live demo ?

Comment: please look there https://codesandbox.io/s/9lqnroooxr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice()` doesn't modify the original array, and perhaps in the last line you meant `splice()`.

This creates as many different canvas elements as items in `arr`:

NOTE: to have vue.js keep track of which element is which inside the `v-for`, it's necessary to specify a *unique* and *stable* value as the `key`. *Uniqueness alone is not sufficient, it must keep the same value associated to the same element, otherwise vue will get confused!*

In your case the index changes when you remove an entry, while the `item` is the value that identifies an element. So you have to specify `:key="item"`.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      arr: [],
    };
  },
  created: function () {
  let arr = [];
  arr.push({id:1});//have one canvas and draw things in the canvas
  arr.push({id:2});//have new canvas and also draw things in the canvas
  arr = arr.slice(0,1);//delete first element, the related canvas and other canvas are disordered
  arr.splice(0,0,{id:3});//canvas tags show same disordered
  console.log(arr);
  this.arr = arr;
  }
})
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <canvas v-for="(item,index) in arr" :key="item"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, splice, sorry ,I typed a wrong word. I mean that before change Array arr by   other way——click a button,  all canvas have drawn many graphics. Change the element of arr don't aright control related canvas tags, the graphics of the canvas of the deleted or changed order by arr  don't aright show.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand your problem. Could you create a simple demo of the problem, for example using [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/vue) ?

Comment: thank you very much, please look there https://codesandbox.io/s/9lqnroooxr

Comment: you have to use `:key="item"` instead of `:key="index"` because your unique key that identifies the content is `item`, while the index changes when you remove items, thus confusing vue. As a general principle, the `:key` should be unique and stable (identifying always the same element).

Comment: also, even if not necessary, I'd suggest using a separate component for your canvas. This allows to simplify the code and making it more clean. For example: [https://codesandbox.io/s/8kx1w64300](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kx1w64300). If you think this answer is satisfying, please consider marking it as accepted :-)